# jQuery animation not shown because content hasn't loaded

Tags: jquery, html, animation, load, slide

**Question One:** I am using callbacks to do 3 things when a link is clicked

I think the issue might be on loading, the load function finishes but the content still doesnt show up for couple of seconds, why does that happen? Could it be that the load function doesn't recognize the size of the images that getting loaded but only calculates the size of the html page?

1) SlideUp current div(container)

2) Load HTML content(images) inside $iframe(div)

3) SlideDown $iframe div which has the content

Problem is the animations are not displayed when viewed in online environment. 
It only works on localhost where everything happens instantly.

```
$(".container").slideUp(500, function(){
    $iframe.load($mylink, function(){
        $iframe.slideDown(500)}
)});
```

**Question Two:**

I use a button to close the div that loads the html content. When that happens I have to empty the div so that the height of each content loaded is reset, but .empty() just makes content disappear instantly. I tried to animate it first then empty the div but it doesn't work like when empty is used by itself:

```
$close.click(function(){ $iframe.slideUp(500, function(){$iframe.empty()}), $(".container").slideDown(500)});
```

Comment: for question 1, have you tried doing the loading first then the slideup, then the slidedown? for question 2, what's the issue exactly? what's not working as expected?

Comment: Yes, I just tried that. I removed the slideUp and did load then slide down but it doesn't work(animation doesn't show). About second Q, when using slideUp(or animation in general) and then use empty is like not using empty at all for some reason. It works great by itself though...

Comment: animation doesn't show but does the element remain hidden? or is it showing but without animation?

Comment: It is showing. I tried to slide it up and then down to compensate, it works but the animation becomes laggy, have look at this video: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q82qtpm7tdudowm/jquery.mp4 - The animation slows down only when uploaded online, not on localhost.

Comment: If I delay the animation, it works great but how can I calculate the time it needs to load each html's content instead of using a number? `$iframe.load($mylink, function(){ $iframe.slideUp(0, function(){$iframe.delay(500).slideDown(500);}); });`

Comment: Maybe using the [load event handler](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) could help you?

Comment: I am already using it? but it doesn't seem to calculate the data loaded correctly that's why I have to add the delay.

Comment: that's not the same method, you're using the ajax load method, the event handler is supposed to fire when an element and all sub elements have been loaded, so you would first call ajax load and then attach the load handler

Comment: That's a bit confusing, could you show me an example? or implement it on my code above?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37004/discussion-between-koala-dev-and-zefs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory this should work to fire the animations after all the loaded contents have been... loaded:

```
//This is ajax load()
$iframe.load($mylink, function(){ 
    //This is event handler load()
    $iframe.load(function(){
        $iframe.slideDown(500);
    });
});
```

The thing is, I'm not sure about the effectiveness of the load event handler based on the caveats mentioned in [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

**UPDATE**

It turns out that the load event does not correctly handle the loading of new elements in a div, it doesn't get triggered. I believe the most sensible solution would be to use an actual `<iframe>` which does trigger the load event whenever a new "src" is loaded:

```
$iframe.attr('src', $mylink).load(function () {
    //set the height of the iframe to fit it's content
    $iframe.height($iframe[0].contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight);
    $iframe.slideDown(500);
});
```

**UPDATE 2**

Seeing how the iframe solution is not cross-browser, maybe this hack could work:

```
$iframe.load($mylink, function (){
    var $imgs = $iframe.find('img'),
        count = 0;
    $imgs.load(function(){
        if (++count == $imgs.length){
            //all images have been loaded
            $iframe.slideDown();
        }
    });
});
```

We go back to using a div, then after the content is inserted in the DOM, we add a load event handler for all images added and perform the animation when all are loaded.

Here's the **[new demo](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/QNQv9/22/)**

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to work. The content just "pops" when using this method. The slideDown seems to get ignored.

Comment: So koala_dev I was playing with the iframe version of your code and it works great except one little glitch. Sometimes when a link is clicked there is a blink going on, right before the slide down triggers. You can actually see it on your jsfiddle as well. Any idea why that happens? Also, apparently it doesn't work on Firefox & IE.

Comment: Also, if you you have multiple links, the animations don't play when clicking them: http://jsfiddle.net/QNQv9/18/

Comment: I do see the glitch but only when there are multiple links, and yes I just did some test and couldn't get it to work in Firefox, it always reports a height of 0, seems like this won't be a viable solution after all

Comment: By the way, if an html file has SWF or iframe in it instead of an image, how do I add it? I suppose like so? `$iframe.find('img, iframe, object')`. The iframe worked, but not the object. Any idea how to deal with the swf's? I could add them on iframes but...

Comment: Actually there is a problem if I load the swf inside an iframe. The function doesn't seem to work correct on Firefox/IE(sometimes the iframe which contains the swf doesn't load). That doesn't happen on Chrome/Opera where it loads correctly.